# Confuse rails' model and migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, migration

Good Morning Guys.

i really need your help. Can anybody give me an explanation about the relationship between Model and Migration. 
I still don't get it. Or may be you can give me the link of a good article.

Thank you very much
and I'm sorry for my English

Comment: Here you go:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets learn about `Active Records` first. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-active-records.htm) is good explanation.

Rails Active Records provides an interface and binding between the tables in a relational database and the Ruby program code that manipulates database records. Actually this active record file refers Model!

And Rails Migration allows you to use Ruby to define changes to your database schema, making it possible to use a version control system to keep things synchronized with the actual code. **Learn more [here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-migrations.htm)**

It's pretty simple and interesting, right? :)

Comment: Thank you rony36. let me ask another question. If i run this command "rails generate model Product" it will create Products table, won't it?
And if i run this command "rails generate migration CreateProducts" will it create a model called Product?

Comment: no, when you run `rails generate model Product` it generates a model and a migration file. Inside this migration file you need to define Products table. Then if you run `rake db:migrate` it'll generates "Products" table. Besides `rails generate migration CreateProducts` create only migration file.

Comment: Thank You rony36. And this is really silly question? is it alright if we just run "rails generate migration" command without run "rails generate Model" command?

Comment: It just creates a migration file to modify your database. Say, you need to create just a database table, you can do it by creating a migration file. And migrating this migration file. :)

Comment: Thank You rony :). finally i get it. Rony, do you know any great forum for newbie like me?

Comment: you are welcome. :). I like this forum: https://www.ruby-forum.com/ and these tutorials are life savior http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/. And most importantly you can find anything here in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

A model is the class represents your object (Person, Campaign, User etc...)
The Migration is a file contains the description of the database table for this model.
when you execute `rake db:migrate` it will take the migrate files and generate the database tables.
this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) is a bit long but has all you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

The model can be viewed as a plain old relational database. In order to create such a database you must create a migration file that specifies the table names and table columns to be created. To actually make the changes take effect you must run rails migrate. Migration can be very beneficial at times. You can rollback the changes you have made to undo them. In the migration you should specify how to undo the changes as well (Unless you use the change method, but this cannot be used for everything).

Comment: Might be better to infer that a Model is basically a representation of an underlying record structure in a database table. That representation (not meaning the record) can be modified to add all sorts of extension methods to the model without changing or affecting the underlying data store.